# Try to Put Functions into one Button Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

plz can someone help, i try to put functions into one button Tkinter but it didn't work. i try to do image color conversion manually with opencv formula. But when i try to run it with tkinter button it didn't nothing.

```
def convertBGRtoHSV(image):
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    rows = image.shape[0]
    cols = image.shape[1]
    sample = (image * (1/255.0))
    B,G,R = cv2.split(sample)

    V = np.zeros((rows, cols)[:2],dtype=np.float64)
    S = np.zeros((rows, cols)[:2],dtype=np.float64)
    H = np.zeros((rows, cols)[:2],dtype=np.float64)



    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            V[i,j] = max(B[i,j],G[i,j],R[i,j])
            Min_RGB = min(B[i,j],G[i,j],R[i,j])


            if V[i,j] != 0.0:
                S[i,j] = ((V[i,j] - Min_RGB) / V[i,j])
            else:
                S[i,j] = 0.0

            if V[i,j] == R[i,j]:
                H[i,j] = 60*(G[i,j] - B[i,j])/(V[i,j] - Min_RGB)
            elif V[i,j] == G[i,j]:
                H[i,j] = 120 + 60*(B[i,j] - R[i,j])/(V[i,j] - Min_RGB)
            elif V[i,j] == B[i,j]:
                H[i,j] = 240 + 60*(R[i,j] - G[i,j])/(V[i,j] - Min_RGB)

            if H[i,j] < 0:
                H[i,j] = H[i,j] + 360


        V = 255.0 * V
        S = 255.0 * S
        H = H/2
        hsv = np.round(cv2.merge((H,S,V)))
        return hsv.astype(np.uint8)

    percobaan = convertBGRtoHSV(image)
    H = crophsv[:,:,0]                                 #Mengambil Nilai H pada Gambar
    S = crophsv[:,:,1]                                 #Mengambil Nilai S pada Gambar
    V = crophsv[:,:,2]                                 #Mengambil Nilai V pada Gambar

data = (H)
print(data)
btn = Button(gui, text='Select A Image', width=15,height=3, bd='5', command=[convertBGR2HSV()])
btn.place(x=500, y=650)
btn.pack
```

when i try running with opencv library tkinter button works and get all hue
the mode hue is all 0

when im using library opencv it work.may god bless anyone who help me. Because im beginner.

Answer (score 2):

What you're passing for `command` (i.e. `[convertBGR2HSV()]`) doesn't make any sense. Think about what it's doing: calling the function `convertBGR2HSV` and putting its return value in a list, which is then used as `command`.

`command` is the function that you want to be called when the button is pressed, so that the code in it is run at that time. So, it doesn't make sense for you to call it yourself. Instead you just need to pass the function, e.g.

`btn = Button(gui, text='Select A Image', width=15,height=3, bd='5', command=convertBGR2HSV)`

If you want to do multiple things when the button is pressed, then write a function that does that and pass that as `command`, e.g.

```
def do_several_things():
    do_thing_1()
    do_thing_2()
    do_thing_3()

...

button = Button(..., command=do_several_things)
```